# How to merge two dataframes and replace the null values with the other's?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that have some columns in common. For example, the first dataframe:

```
A    B C D    G
null 1 2 3    6
4    5 6 null 7
```

And the second one:

```
A B C D E F
2 1 2 3 4 5
4 5 6 8 8 8
```

How to combine them so that the null values disappear and are replaced by the values from the second dataframe?

```
A B C D E F G
2 1 2 3 4 5 6
4 5 6 8 8 8 7
```

I tried using the concat method, but the common columns aren't overlapped, but added to the end of the first dataframe.

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Comment: What about using boolean arrays, for instance: `df1.replace(np.nan, 0) + df2[df1.isna()].replace(np.nan, 0)`

Answer (score 6):

Try via `combine_first()`:

```
out=df1.combine_first(df2)
```

output of `out`:

```
     A      B   C   D       E   F   G
0   2.0     1   2   3.0     4   5   6
1   4.0     5   6   8.0     8   8   7
```

If needed chain `astype()` method with `combine_first()`:

```
out=df1.combine_first(df2).astype(int)
```

output of `out`:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   2   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   4   5   6   8   8   8   7
```

Comment: Elegant solution as always.

Comment: @Don'tAccept learned from you guys ***;)***

Comment: @AnuragDabas sorry, but this doesn't really work for me. There are some values missing from the first df, as well from the second dataframe. How can I combine them so that the final one has not NaN values? If I use your method, i get either two entries for the same row, with different values, or one row with some Nan values.

Comment: @viktor_dmitry are both df's are of same length?

Comment: @AnuragDabas, no, one has 2018 elements and one has 19.

Comment: @viktor_dmitry If `combine_first()` if giving you 2 rows then that was due to overlap and if you are getting nan thatwas due to the presence of NaN's in both df's

Comment: @viktor_dmitry if you can able to fill nan's of any column 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' in both df's then you can also able to merge them onthe nearest key values

Comment: @viktor_dmitry try changing the order `product_df.combine_first(error_df)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234152/discussion-between-viktor-dmitry-and-anurag-dabas).